# How to download angular projects and import my browser

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I want Download Angular Project source code and run angular application on browser in my system

[Angular Upload Excel Pdf](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upload-excel-pdf-ncw1vf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fgenerator.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fgenerator.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fgenerator.component.ts)

first I download this project from source code in local desktop
then I open the file and put this command

```
npm install node--modules --save
```

but i get the following error

```
npm install node--modules --save
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@7.2.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"7.2.11" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"7.0.4" from @angular/compiler-cli@7.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~7.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-26T02_53_24_422Z-debug-0.log
```

does it have to do with the arugula version?

Answer (score 0):

Please install the required packages with the following command.

```
 npm i
```